# How to configure settings.php for Drupal site with Varnish and CDN?

Tags: configuration, proxies, cdn

I am completely new to the back-end issues, so I would appreciate any detailed answers with explanation.

We need to configure our settings.php file so that it works with Varnish and CDN.  Currently, it's commented out by default.  I read the comments over and over in the settings.php, and it doesn't make much sense, or I don't know how to provide the information.

> In  the most simple scenario, the proxy server will add an
>    X-Forwarded-For header to the request that contains the client IP
>   address. However, HTTP headers are vulnerable to spoofing, where a
>    malicious client could bypass restrictions by setting the
>    X-Forwarded-For header directly. Therefore, Drupal's proxy configuration requires the IP addresses of all remote proxies to be specified in $conf['reverse_proxy_addresses'] to work correctly.
>
> ...
>
> In order for this setting to be used you must specify every possible
>     reverse proxy IP address in $conf['reverse_proxy_addresses'].
>    If a complete list of reverse proxies is not available in your
>    environment (for example, if you use a CDN) you may set the
>    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] variable directly in settings.php.
>    Be aware, however, that it is likely that this would allow IP
>    address spoofing unless more advanced precautions are taken.

Several things that concern me:

1. What comments do I need to uncomment?
2. Since I'm using a CDN, I guess I'll have to use: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].  But what are the "advanced precautions" available that I can take to prevent IP spoofing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know what you're doing (and to a certain extent even if you do) it's probably better to use modules to accomplish what you're trying to do:

1. [Varnish](https://www.drupal.org/project/varnish)
2. [CDN](https://www.drupal.org/project/cdn)

This is mainly due to the extra configuration and set-up help you get with the modules